# How do I buy cars in GTA online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

When buying cars online, some pictures just have the letter 's'. what does that mean? Also, do you need a garage to buy cars?

Answer (score 8):

The "S" mean that those cars need to be stolen and brought back to Simeon to be available. And yes you'll need a garage to buy cars online.